# how can I merge xmi files?

Tags: tortoisesvn, xmi

We created a branch out of trunk (using TortoiseSVN) and now we need to merge it back. The problem is that the files are data models' xmi files which is not allowing us to resolve conflicts to merge it back. The editor just shows loads of weird characters or interrogation marks.

I couldn't find much on the net about solutions for it. Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if [EMF Compare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) could help

Answer (score 0):

Probably your files contains binary data but they are being considered as text by TortoiseSVN, confusing the TortoiseMerge process.

By the way, if the branch files are the most recent, consider resolve the conflict using the branch version of the files.

Additionally, think about mark your XMI files with property `svn:mime-type application/octet-stream`. This will avoid TortoiseMerge to misbehaviours.